# Adding rendered item position to an array of items?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'd like to add the positional coordinates of each object as it's rendered so that I can then designate it as a drop zone.

I can get one piece of data into the `objLocation`, but obviously, it keeps overwriting as each `SubComponent` is rendered. What is the correct way to built that array of object locations?

```
const data = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
]


export default class Viewport extends Component {
    this.state = {
      objLocation = [],
    }

    render() {
      return (
        {data.map( d => {
          return(
            <SubComponent onLayout={this.getLayout} id={d.id} />
          )
        })}
      )
    }


    getLayout = (e) => (
      const obj = { 
        width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
        height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
        x: e.nativeEvent.layout.x,
        y: e.nativeEvent.layout.y,
      }
      this.setState({
        objLocation: obj
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs).

```
this.setState({ 
  arrayvar: this.state.arrayvar.concat([newelement])
})


ES6 With Spread operator.
this.setState({
  arrayvar: [...this.state.arrayvar, newelement]
})
```